# Using the Right (second) CTRL key in Sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am working on automation of a customised mainframe application which uses the Right CTRL and Right ENTER. Is there any way I can implement this using Sikuli?
Also, I can't install any other remapper software like autoHotKey etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli has no platform related knowlegde at all. But AutoIt can do this, and you can call AutoIt from Sikuli. No remap just key-press: Send("{RCTRL}"), Send("{RSHIFT}") etcetera.

Reference:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm